# Utility to show disk IO read/write summary for a task/command/program

Tags: disk, monitoring, io

I'm pretty sure the Linux kernel has a feature which allows to track **all** the reads and writes (IO) of an application and **all** its children however I haven't seen any utilities which can calculate it and show it.

For instance for CPU time you could simply use `time` and get neat CPU use information:

```bsh
$ time cat --version > /dev/null

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I'm looking for something similar in regard to IO, e.g.

```
$ calc_io task
Bytes read: 123456
Bytes written: 0
```

Of course, we have `/proc/$PID/io` which contains runtime information but tracking it for applications which spawn and destroy children dynamically, e.g. web-browsers seems like a daunting task. I guess if you run `strace -fF firefox` then monitor all children being spawned and try to track in real time `/proc/$PID/io` - nah, seems like too difficult to implement and then how often will you poll this file for information? Children may exist for a split second.

Another idea is to use `cgroups` but then what if I don't want to use them? Also I've checked `/sys/fs/cgroup` and I don't see any relevant statistics.

Comment: The getdelays not enough for you? http://blog.foool.net/wp-content/uploads/linuxdocs/accounting.pdf   (8. page....)

Comment: `IO count delay total 0 0` - doesn't look like what I need at all. *The per-task delay accounting functionality measures the delays experienced by a
task while
a) waiting for a CPU (while being runnable)
b) completion of synchronous block I/O initiated by the task*

Comment: What about pidstat -T ? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidstat.1.html

Comment: `glances` seems able to do this on disk I/O on a per second basis.

Comment: I found this: https://pyroute2.org/pyroute2-0.3.4/taskstats.html 
It's exciting. The taskstats structure still available more than 10 years, and I can not found any good solution based on this except the getdelays....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post and found it very interesting. I thought this problem was not that difficult since the question you are asking is quite natural after all.

I could only find an imperfect and incomplete solution. I decided to post it anyway, as the question was not answered yet.
This requires a system with systemd and cgroups2 (I read what you said about it but it might be interesting to see this solution). I learned about both, I don't master them.
I tested only on an arch-based linux distribution.

```
~]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/user\@1000.service.d/override.conf 
[Service]
Delegate=pids memory io
```

It seems that you need to "delegate" io controller to your "user systemd sub tree" to use this as an unprivileged user (I can't point one specific place. man systemd.resource-control. https://systemd.io/CGROUP_DELEGATION . https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/cgroups#As_unprivileged_user )

```
~]$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/my.slice 
[Slice]
IOAccounting=true
```

Then create a slice with IOAccounting enabled to run you processes in.

reboot

```
~]$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh 

dd if=/dev/random of=/home/yarl/bar bs=1M count=7
dd if=/dev/random of=/home/yarl/bar bs=1M count=3

~]$ systemd-run --user --slice=my.slice /home/yarl/foo.sh

~]$ systemctl --user status my.slice
● my.slice - Slice /my
     Loaded: loaded (/home/yarl/.config/systemd/user/my.slice; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2021-11-07 20:25:20 CET; 12s ago
         IO: 100.0K read, 10.0M written
      Tasks: 0
     Memory: 3.2M
        CPU: 162ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/my.slice

nov. 07 20:25:20 pbpro systemd[1229]: Created slice Slice /my.
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, kinda convoluted but it works. Great many thanks. Would be nice to get a utility which automates all of that or a command which does that automatally. We already have e.g. systemd-run --user -t -p MemoryMax=300M command which operates with cgroups which doesn't need to edit anything and works under a normal user account.